# Apple's official sample HLSCatalog dose not work?

Tags: ios, avasset

I am trying Apple's sample project `HLSCatalog` for downloading `HLS` stream, but `AVAssetDownloadDelegate` methods are not called when I pressed the "Download" button for Basic Stream. However, `urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?)` and `urlSession(_ session: URLSession, assetDownloadTask: AVAssetDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL)` are called when I pressed "Cancel" to cancel the download.

The sample project is run on iPhone 6+ (real device), iOS 10.3.2.
Wifi connection and 4G are both tested.

Does anyone have the same issue?

Comment: Sorry. Have no idea what happened to my iPhone. The sample project works fine after rebooting my iPhone. -_-

Comment: On an unrelated note, does the Advanced Stream download work for you? As in does it get stuck in an endless loop trying to download extra media selections?